# How to abbreviate a two word name in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to abbreviate a first name and a last name. For example, if I enter **Diesan Romero** (that's my name), I need to return the initials **D.R** with that intermediate point.

I had no idea where to start. So I went to the Python documentation and tried to convert the text string to a list, iterate the list, and then choose those characters that were uppercase. This is the code that I have achieved so far.

```
def convertToList(name):
    lista = []
    for i in name:
        if i.isupper(): 
            lista.append(i)
        return lista


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(convertToList("Diesan Romero"))
```

In that code I try to create the list, but it only returns me one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your names will always be in the format - “first last”, you may be able to do the following:

```
def get_initials(name):

    names = name.split(' ')
    return ' '.join([f"{n[0]}." for n in names])


print(get_initials('John Doe'))
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try to better understand the way you use split and join in this case.

Comment: This answer does not actually do what you asked.

Answer (score 3):

```
def convertToList(name):
    final_name = []
    name_list = name.split()
    for i in name_list:
        final_name.append(i[0])
    print '.'.join(final_name)


convertToList('Diesan Romero')
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are returning lista as soon as you first find an upper-case letter. Try de-indenting the "return" by two tabs to shift it after the end of the for loop.